# Loading three tables using Entity Framework include and lazy loading

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am using Entity Framework code-first, I have 3 tables, `TableA` is the master table, `TableB` is master table of `TableC`. I have reference key of `TableA` in `TableC`, it means to load `TableB`, I have to go through `TableC`.

TableA has columns PKA, Col1A, Col2A
TableB has Columns PKB, Col1B, Col2B
TableC has Columns PKC, Col1C, Col2C

Can someone please let me know how I can incorporate in my Linq query in Entity Framework and load all those three tables using include statement and write a Linq query, any help please - thanks in advance.

Comment: Please share some code to begin with

Comment: It is a need of mine, what code can I provide you, like what? Something like this:    var data = ClassCloner.Clean(
               (from x in Context.EnforcementSectionManager.GetAll()
                                 .Include("Branch.ViolationTypes.ViolationType")
                where x.EnforcementSectionId == id
                select x).FirstOrDefault(),
                    "Branch",
                    "Branch.ViolationTypes.ViolationType"
               );
            return data; But I got some gap in using EF hence I am struggling in writing query buddy

Comment: Anything that could demo the problem better. maybe a diagram of the tables with references among them. because inferring relationship logic from reading a text is not the most desirable way possible :)

Comment: Hi Buddy, I re-framed the question little bit more in detail, can you please look into the issue now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i take it, `TableC` has dependency to both A and B. and you want to query `TableC` for its values along with respective values from A,B. If my assumption is right then you are looking for:

```
var list = context.TableC
    .Include(t => t.TableACollection)
    .Include(t => t.TableBCollection);
```

for selecting only certain fields from those tables:

```
var list = context.TableC
    .Include(t => t.TableACollection.Select(c => c.Col1A))
    .Include(t => t.TableBCollection.Select(c => c.Col1B));
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: @Abdul good, then would you mind giving me an upvote and best answer may be, in case it really helped.

Comment: Yes I did buddy